# how do I check the boot processes?

Tags: boot, grub2, startup

my computer (Ubuntu Mate 20.04 ) is taking over a minute to boot, and I am not sure why. It seems to be something to do with a boot process on this specific hard drive.

from dmesg:

```
...
[    1.922970] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[    2.328482] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    2.530339] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input7
[    3.256967] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
[   34.601941] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
...
```

there seems to be 30 seconds right there, I dont have Btrfs, Im not sure why its checking for it, or whatever its doing.

then I have this:

```
[   38.739280] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[  125.248857] Process accounting resumed
```

I have no clue what Process accounting is.

I took this photo of the boot process:
[image]
the very last line in this photo is what I want to find, and fix, it takes a minute and a half to run, every time I boot my computer. It happens in safemode, and on normal boot. is there a single tool for listing boot processes? I dont want to reinstall. I have tried checking the disk filesystem, the issue persists. I have done SMART disk analysis, and the hard drive is fine.

The command `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 38.388s
└─multi-user.target @1min 38.388s
  └─lxc.service @1min 38.330s +57ms
    └─lxc-net.service @1min 38.184s +143ms
      └─network-online.target @1min 38.179s
        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 30.737s +7.440s
          └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.360s +374ms
            └─dbus.service @1min 30.355s
              └─basic.target @1min 30.316s
                └─sockets.target @1min 30.315s
                  └─snapd.socket @1min 30.310s +4ms
                    └─sysinit.target @1min 30.280s
                      └─systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.service @2>
                        └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @1.538s
                          └─system.slice @251ms
                            └─-.slice @251ms
```

and the command `systemd-analyze time`

```
$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 34.552s (kernel) + 2min 7.682s (userspace) = 2min 42.235s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 38.388s in userspace
```

Comment: isn't that fsck running a check or repair on the filesystem? you have a partial UUID there, can you identify that partition.. you could probably temporarily turn the check on it off in fstab and test if it still happens on boot...

Comment: inspect boot process time with `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze time` - Please [edit] your post and add the outpput of these commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I still would like to know a best practice, or a more efficent means of troubleshooting this type of nonsense, in the boot process.

when I saw `W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=66f2ea6d-cfab-4410-933b-763fb6c6bc83: but no matching swap device is available`.. ... I checked gparted, and found that I have no swap space partition. (that should be fine I've got loads of RAM) but this setup, seems to be that I might have had one at some point, why I dont have one now, that part is a mystery. I opened up /etc/fstab, and commented out the swap partition (that had the same UUID as the disk that was taking forever to check on boot.)

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=66f2ea6d-cfab-4410-933b-763fb6c6bc83 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

why was it on /dev/sda5? great question, I have no idea.

So then I went over to `sudo vim /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` 
and commented out the refference to the swap partition with the offending UUID.

`#RESUME=UUID=66f2ea6d-cfab-4410-933b-763fb6c6bc83`

Then, I updated initramfs
`$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

and rebooted just to see what would happen. I booted up in seconds.

So my boot time issue is solved... but if there is a better way of troubleshooting this type of error, I would love to know about it. I read all sorts of stuff, and saw many users having similar issues. I tried the `boot-repair` utility, it did nothing to fix this.  It was literally months until I got a clue from an error I saw while trying to update Mate, thinking that some userspace App might have been the issue.