# My Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has become too long to boot, like 5 minutes, how could I reduce this too long boot time?

Tags: boot, 22.04

I run Ubuntu on a corei7 dell ladtop.

It takes 3 to 5 minutes to boot.

And, after having boot, and after having log in my user session, I have to wait again for 3 to 5 other additional minutes before Ubuntu responds normally without any lagging.

It becomes quiet a bit boring.

Is there something to do ? Or is it normal ?

I add some information bellow, the returns of commands: `systemd-analyze critical-chain`, `systemd-analyze time`, `journalctl -p 3 -b`, ``.

**Get info on boot processes**

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 12.406s
└─multi-user.target @2min 12.405s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @1min 2.287s +1min 10.113s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 2.112s +169ms
      └─network.target @1min 2.077s
        └─NetworkManager.service @47.861s +14.213s
          └─dbus.service @47.858s
            └─basic.target @47.760s
              └─sockets.target @47.759s
                └─cups.socket @56.673s
                  └─sysinit.target @47.188s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @46.891s +296ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @45.318s +1.563s
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @7.754s +37.563s
                          └─systemd-remount-fs.service @7.023s +727ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @6.881s
                              └─-.mount @6.803s
                                └─-.slice @6.803s
```

**Get info on time to boot**

```
systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 12.359s (kernel) + 2min 12.474s (userspace) = 2min 24.834s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 12.406s in userspace
```

**Get info on problems during boot:**

```
journalctl -p 3 -b
mars 29 08:35:21 name_of_my_machine kernel: efi: memattr: Failed to map EFI Memory Attributes table @ 0x8c9d5098
mars 29 08:35:21 name_of_my_machine kernel: ioremap error for 0x8f8aa000-0x8f8ab000, requested 0x2, got 0x0
mars 29 08:35:58 name_of_my_machine kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ PRIVRING ]
mars 29 08:35:58 name_of_my_machine kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
mars 29 08:36:21 name_of_my_machine thermald[1192]: Unsupported condition 39 (Power_personality)
mars 29 08:36:21 name_of_my_machine thermald[1192]: Unsupported condition 39 (Power_personality)
mars 29 08:36:21 name_of_my_machine thermald[1192]: Unsupported condition 4 (Motion)
mars 29 08:36:21 name_of_my_machine thermald[1192]: Unsupported condition 39 (Power_personality)
mars 29 08:36:21 name_of_my_machine thermald[1192]: Unsupported condition 4 (Motion)
mars 29 08:36:21 name_of_my_machine thermald[1192]: Unsupported condition 39 (Power_personality)
mars 29 08:36:21 name_of_my_machine thermald[1192]: Unsupported condition 39 (Power_personality)
mars 29 08:36:21 name_of_my_machine thermald[1192]: Unsupported conditions are present
mars 29 08:36:27 name_of_my_machine bluetoothd[1157]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
mars 29 08:36:54 name_of_my_machine gnome-session-binary[1594]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
mars 29 08:36:54 name_of_my_machine gnome-session-binary[1594]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
mars 29 08:37:03 name_of_my_machine kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ PRIVRING ]
mars 29 08:37:25 name_of_my_machine kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ PRIVRING ]
mars 29 08:37:50 name_of_my_machine gdm-password][2074]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
mars 29 08:37:54 name_of_my_machine kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ PRIVRING ]
mars 29 08:38:04 name_of_my_machine systemd[2083]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
mars 29 08:38:04 name_of_my_machine systemd[2083]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
mars 29 08:38:04 name_of_my_machine systemd[2083]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
mars 29 08:38:05 name_of_my_machine systemd[2083]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
mars 29 08:38:24 name_of_my_machine gdm-launch-environment][1415]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
mars 29 08:39:47 name_of_my_machine systemd[2083]: Failed to start Tracker file system data miner.
mars 29 08:41:17 name_of_my_machine systemd[2083]: Failed to start Tracker file system data miner.
```

Get info on boot disk:

```
sudo parted -l

Modèle : ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disque /dev/sda : 1000GB
```

Comment: see the commands here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288883/how-do-i-check-the-boot-processes  find the offending service(s), find what to do with it (disable/mask/other solution) if I had to guess: it is a network problem (that is started during boot and used just after login).

Comment: This is not normal. There is something getting stuck in the start up process. These things usually have a timeout so they sit there doing nothing for a period, typically 90 seconds in my experience. The suggestion from @Rinzwind is good. You might also like to try `journalctl -p 3 -b` once your system is running. It will show any thing which is encountering an error. Not all of these need to be fixed but anything slowing start up should be shown in some way.

Comment: What is the harddisk that is booted from?

Comment: I add some information coming from commands. I'm not sure what to do with them. There are some errors during the boot process.

Comment: That is a 5400 RPM harddisk. a 2, 3m boot is likely normal. The biggest gain you will get is by replacing the boot disk by an ssd and transforming you current disk to a personal disk.